# Array setters does not do anything

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3

I need to change a text field every time values in an array is updated, and I tried putting the code in the setter. However, the code is not being called. Even if I do this

```
public function set resources(value:*) {
    //this function does not seem to matter at all
}
```

Nothing happens. I think AS3 overrides setters for arrays, how do I get the functionality other than inserting a changeTextFields(); every time I change the array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll address your points in reverse order:

1. There is no programmatic way of knowing that values inside an array have changed. As the programmer, you must perform some notifying action (e.g. raise an event or call a function) when you know that the values have changed. In you case this is calling the `changeTextFields()` method whenever the values have changed..
2. This is not directly related with `setters`. i.e. there is not any special behaviour for array setters or any other type of `setter` methods.

All setters do is let you treat a method as a mutable object property (that is, you invoke them with the `=` operator instead of the round brackets):

```
public class SetterExample {

    private var _resources:* = null;
    // Example setter method.
    public function set resources(value:*) {
        this._resources = value;
    }

    // Regular method.
    public function assignResources(value:*) {
        this._resources = value;
    }

}

/*===============================
// Later on:
===============================*/

var ex:SetterExample = new SetterExample();

// Here we use the '=' symbol instead of round brackets to invoke the setter.
ex.resources = object1;

// This is not a setter, so we invoke 'assignResources' with the round brackets, passing in our parameters.
ex.assignResources(object1);
```

Answer (score 0):

To get an event dispatched when an Array instance is modified, wrap the array in an [mx.utils.ArrayCollection](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/collections/ArrayCollection.html).

Don't let the `mx.utils` Flex package scare you... with the "Merged" linkage this class usage should not add a lot to your SWF as there is not much to it.

A similar issue exists when you want notification of changes made to basic [Object](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Object.html) instances (eg: when using them as an associated array).  In this case, for notification of changes to Object instances you wrap the instance in an [ObjectProxy](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/utils/ObjectProxy.html).  This is in `mx.collections`, but is also a pretty lightweight inclusion for AS3 projects.